# Filtering with OR vs IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A common filter in SQL procs goes something like:

`WHERE (@a = 0 OR @a = a)`

Obviously the idea being to filter on `a` if a positive parameter was provided to the proc, but to otherwise show all results. There are, of course, different variations of this that account for the possibility of nulls. But taking the specific example given above, would it be identical to write it as follows?

`WHERE @a in (0, a)`

Comment: @WAMLeslie It is.

Comment: @WAMLeslie Wait, just to verify, you are saying the two versions are *not* the same if a is a column? Can you help me understand what the difference would be?

Comment: @WAMLeslie No, that's not what I want. I'm not certain what I might have said to give that impression? The idea is that if I pass in a 7 then I want it to return only records where a = 7. I don't want to return all rows if a = 7 for any row in the table. That wouldn't make any sense??

Comment: @WAMLeslie But if I pass in 0 then I obviously want it to return all records. Make sense?

Comment: @WAMLeslie Sure it is. It's the value for the current record being evaluated.

Comment: If `a` is a column, it still works because of the context.  `where @a = a` refers to the value of `a` in the row being evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those expressions will produce the same results.

This assumes context:

```
declare @a int
set @a = 1

select *
from [sometable]
where @a in (0, a)
```

...where `a` is an *int* column in the `sometable` table.
In this case, you'll get all records from `sometable` where `a=1`.

Comment: I think the OR is more clear for this stuff.

Comment: Maybe for this extremely simple example.  When you have a long list of values and more complex logic, `IN` combines the values very neatly.

Comment: Maybe, but in this context wouldn't any more be AND/OR WHERE logic and not be put in the same IN. Maybe a different IN. It's most likely me not getting it, but if you have time can you add an example of more complex logic that the IN would simplify?

Comment: @MichaelZ. `x in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` versus `x = 1 or x = 2 or x = 3 or x = 4 or x = 5`. The first one is much less verbose.

Comment: I know how `in` works. I just didn't explain what I was saying very well. I would imagine this being applied in a dynamic filter. Like `SELECT * FROM T WHERE (@CUST = '<ALL>' OR [Cust] = @CUST) AND (@CATEGORY = '<ALL>' OR [Category] = @CATEGORY)`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T WHERE @CUST IN ('<ALL>', [Cust]) AND @CATEGORY IN ('<ALL>', [Category])` - looks better on multiple lines